# When can definite integration be numerically computable?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request, numerical-methods, computability

under what condition,can the  integration  $$\int_{\Delta}f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n, \text{where  } \Delta  \text{  is integration domain defined by function},f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)  \text{  is the integrated function }$$
be numerically computable?

I think the sufficient and necessary  condition must depend on $\Delta$ and $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n$.When $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n$ is integratable, the condition must depend on the function that determine the domain $\Delta$. So the question may restated as :what kind of the two function makes the integration numerically computable? It seems to be easy, when know the integration is Lebsegue or Riemann integration.

Comment: What is your definition of "numerically computable"? For example, is $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx$ numerically computable or not?

Comment: @5xum, it is numerically computable. By numerically computable, I mean we can compute the integration to any precision we require

Comment: Using that definition, any integral of an integrable function is computable if you have a strong enough computer, since by definition, there must exist a subdivision of $\Delta$ such that the riemann sums for that division are in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the limit, i.e. the integral.

On the other hand, since no computer has infinite precision, almost no function is numerically computable: you cannot integrate $e^{-x^2}$ up to $10^{100}$ digits because no computer on the world is strong enough...

Comment: @5xum Actually there are integrable functions whose integral isn't computable by any computer. For example, integrate the function $1$ over a set with non-computable measure.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Replace "integrable" with "riemann integrable" in my comment.

Comment: @5xum I don't see what that changes. Suppose $a<b$ with $b-a$ a noncomputable real. Then the constant function $1$ is Riemann integrable with $\int_{a}^{b} 1 = b-a$ noncomputable.